# android memory doesn't clear properly

Tags: android, memory

I'm currently making an app which often switches activities.
I have noticed that when i call finish() and started a new activity the previous one does not clear properly.

When I switch between two activity for a couple of times the RAM keeps increasing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LevelSelect.this, LevelPlay.class);
    intent.putExtra("levelNumber", levelNumber);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

This is the code that switches.

I have also included a picture from android studio monitoring my memory usage. You can clearly see that switching back does not mean that the memory is the same as the last time the activity was used.

[screenshot of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPbNM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect some memory leaks you might have on your Activities.
Check rotating your device, and see if your memory goes up as well, if true, definitely a mem leak issue.

Have a look in these links to debug, trace your problem

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: My app locks the orientation so I can't try that. I will have a look at those links.

Comment: But how do I know what is the problem or what is not removed at the end of the activity. Because as far as I understand your links I can only see what is allocated and used by the memory.

Comment: You can use the leaky canary as @pratham said, the Eclipse memory analyser that comes with the DDMS.

Comment: Or you can post a bit more of the code, on those two classes so one can have a look and try to find out.  What do you see on logcat? you might have some clues there as well

Answer (score 0):

well GC event is not triggered as soon as u fired Up finish() or something like that You can manually call a GC by

```
System.gc();
```

Also use [leaky canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) for any memory leaks

Comment: When i try to add leaky canary to build.gradle and then sync i get the following error: Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'debugCompile()'
When i try to add leaky canary to my build.gradle and then sync i get the following problem.

Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Illuminandus' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: I did what was on the frontpage of the their github

Comment: make a gist of the gradle file and share it with me on Github my profile
https://github.com/PrathameshKesarkar

Comment: does System.gc() freed up some memory

Comment: how do i share the gist with you? I can only copy paste a link as far as i can see

Comment: System.gc() didn't seem to do that much

Comment: What exactly are you doing like using Bitmap something like that

Comment: I'm building a game that has a ball moving throug a maze. Every wall is an imageview. So there are alot of imageviews, no Bitmaps. The activities that i spoke about are level playing activity and the level selector activity

Comment: did you entered All three dependencies

Comment: I placed all three that were on their github page in my dependencies yes

Comment: no just add debugCompile you have surely not configured the releaseBuild and TestBuild

Comment: I still get the same message. Do I have to do anything with all the files in their github. Download them and place them somewhere for example?

Comment: no what you are saying is for Eclipse those dependence should work

Comment: Okay it is now in the correct dependecies folder. But how do i use it now? I  used this in my onCreate() :LeakCanary.install(getApplication());

But I don't see anything happening.

Comment: hey are you on googlePlus can send me link I will send u request
I don't want to get my answer to be down voted